# How can I find the difference in years between two date columns?

Tags: lubridate

I'm doing research involving the age of teachers when they take certification tests. I have a column labelled Birth.Date and another labelled Test.Date both of these have dates in the format of year-Month-date (1990-12-26). I'm quite new at R and programming, and need to analyze my data.

Tried Lubridate - but could only find directions for individual rows. Not the remotest clue.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! For best results on the site, please post any code you have attempted to solve your problem, you will get a much better response that way!

Comment: What analysis are you looking for? If you are just after per-row differences or means/medians etc then could you just use a spreadsheet?